# Dafny recursive trigger debugging

Tags: recursion, triggers, dafny, finite-group-theory

Following up from a previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75126382/dafny-existence-statement-cause-slowness). I'm trying to extend my definition of an abstract power for all integers.

I thought I setup the triggers correctly but I'm still running into recursive triggers endlessly verifying. Is there a better way to debug recursive triggers than just guessing and checking? I basically sit there with task manager open seeing if z3 is eating all the memory. I hope there is a way to get better visibility about what is happening.

```
function apow<A>(g: Group, elem: A, n: int): A
    decreases n*n
    ensures n == 0 ==> apow(g,elem,n) == g.identity
{
    if n == 0 then g.identity else if n > 0 then g.compose(elem, apow(g, elem, n-1)) else if n < 0 then g.compose(g.inverse(elem), apow(g, elem, n+1)) else g.identity
}

lemma apowClosed<A>(g: Group, elem: A, n: int)
    requires elem in g.elements
    requires g.identity in g.elements
    requires isIdentity(g)
    requires closedComposition(g)
    requires closedInverse(g)
    requires isInverse(g)
    decreases n*n
    ensures apow(g, elem, n) in g.elements
{}

lemma allApowClosed<A>(g: Group, elem: A) 
    requires ValidGroup(g)
    requires elem in g.elements
    ensures forall x: int :: apow(g, elem, x) in g.elements
{
    reveal apow();
    forall x: int {
        apowClosed(g, elem, x);
    }
}

    lemma {:verify true} apowAdditionInt<A>(g: Group<A>, elem: A, n: int, k: int)
        requires elem in g.elements
        // requires ValidGroup(g)
        requires closedComposition(g)
        requires closedInverse(g)
        requires g.identity in g.elements
        requires isIdentity(g);
        requires associativeComposition(g)
        ensures g.compose(apow(g, elem, n), apow(g, elem, k)) == apow(g, elem, n+k)
    {
        allApowClosed(g, elem);
        if k == 0 {
            assert apow(g, elem, k) == g.identity;
            assert g.compose(apow(g, elem, n), g.identity) == apow(g, elem, n+k);
        }else if n == 0 {
            assert apow(g, elem, n) == g.identity;
            assert g.compose(g.identity, apow(g, elem, k)) == apow(g, elem, n+k);
        }else if n > 0 && n+k > k {
            apowPos(g, elem, n);
            apowPos(g, elem, n+k);
            assert apow(g, elem, n-1) in g.elements;
            assert apow(g, elem, k) in g.elements;
            assert apow(g, elem, n+k) in g.elements;
            // assume g.compose(elem, g.compose(apow(g, elem, n-1), apow(g, elem, k))) == g.compose(elem, apow(g, elem, n-1+k));
            calc {
                g.compose(apow(g, elem, n), apow(g, elem, k));
                g.compose(g.compose(elem, apow(g, elem, n-1)), apow(g, elem, k));
                g.compose(elem, g.compose(apow(g, elem, n-1), apow(g, elem, k)));
                == {apowAdditionInt(g,elem, n-1,k);}
                g.compose(elem, apow(g, elem, n-1+k));
                // apow(g, elem, n+k);
            }
        // }else{

        }else{

        }
    }
```

```
 datatype Group<!A> = Group(elements: set<A>, identity: A, compose: (A,A) -> A, inverse: (A) -> A)

    predicate isIdentity<A>(g: Group<A>) {
        forall a :: a in g.elements ==> g.compose(a,g.identity) == a && g.compose(g.identity, a) == a
    }

    predicate closedComposition<A>(g: Group<A>) {
        forall x,y :: x in g.elements && y in g.elements ==> g.compose(x,y) in g.elements
    }

    predicate associativeComposition<A>(g: Group<A>) {
        forall a,b,c :: a in g.elements && b in g.elements && c in g.elements ==> g.compose(g.compose(a,b),c) == g.compose(a, g.compose(b,c))
    }
    predicate closedInverse<A>(g: Group<A>) {
    forall x {:trigger g.inverse(x)} :: x in g.elements ==> g.inverse(x) in g.elements
    }

    predicate isInverse<A>(g: Group<A>) {
    forall x {:trigger g.inverse(x)} :: x in g.elements ==> g.compose(x,g.inverse(x)) == g.identity && g.compose(g.inverse(x),x) == g.identity
    }
```

Comment: There is better way to structure group theory in dafny - https://gist.github.com/rdivyanshu/510deac91e148f2d475a2ad66243b312. I am not sure what problem in your approach is but my  guess is your group datatype is more lenient. Not any laws around compose etc in form of post condition. You have narrowed your acceptable group as form of precondition to functions. But now dafny has to reason/search through it for example application of compose always returns element in group and triggers are not configured correctly to narrow search space

Comment: Can you please provide a minimum workable example? Group is not defined.

Comment: Added the definitions,

Comment: Thank you for the definitions Divyanshu, but I tried to apply to another lemma I already had and it would not verify. I defined groupCompositionInverse but with the module construction it does not verify but does with the predicate version. How could I change it to verify with modules? https://gist.github.com/hath995/008921599add4c3a1a980c90da9af3c5

Comment: @Hath995, You are almost there you need one more lemma. I have replied to gist

Comment: I appreciate the alternate definitions, but the question remains un-answered, what are methods available to debug triggers? I think the answer might be that there aren't many. Maybe we can suggest this to the Dafny developers.